# How to ignore words before/after pipe in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website in which I want to ignore words before/after pipe in php.

The following php code `<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>` prints the following o/p:

```
| Good Morning
```

In the above o/p, I want pipe not to be visible. It should be like this:

```
Good Morning
```

I tried in the following way but it doesn't seem to work;

```
<?php
$title = the_title();
$textPipe = explode("|", $title); ?>
<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php textPipe[1]; ?></h1>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the code which I have tried above so that it takes words only after pipe.

Comment: `$textPipe` != `textPipe`

Answer (score 1):

You may try, as the [Wordpress Codex suggests](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title):

```php
<?php
$title = get_the_title(); // Notice that get_the_title() RETURNS the title whereas the_title() prints (echo) it.
$textPipe = explode("|", $title); ?>
<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php $textPipe[1]; ?></h1>
```

By the way, you can also use the PHP function `str_replace` (see [PHP str_replace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) if you want to remove the space between the pipe and your actual title:

```php
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
$title = str_replace("| ", "", $title); ?>
<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php $title; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Its missing echo, and your textPipe the correct is $textPipe

## this way:

```
<?php
  $title = the_title();
  $textPipe = explode("|", $title); 
?>
<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php echo $textPipe[1]; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like....

```
<h1 class="featured-block__title"><?php ltrim ( the_title ( ), '| ' ); ?></h1>
```